# Problema de sincronicacion de hilos uzando c

Tags: c

wk03: Synchronize Threads: Problema H2O.
Su programa deberá hacer lo siguiente:

-Leer N y M que son pasados como argumentos desde la línea de comandos
-Crear N Threads de Hidrógeno donde cada hilo que genera una molécula de H.
-Crear M Threads de Oxígeno donde cada hilo que genera una molécula de O.
-Crear 1 hilo de agua que espera hasta que se generen dos moléculas de hidrógeno y una de oxígeno y pueda crear una molécula de agua.
-Considere que las moléculas son contadores en el programa.

El programa deberá imprimir las siguientes salidas de pantalla:

-número de moléculas de agua generadas.
-número de moléculas de hidrógeno que generadas y restantes.
-número de moléculas de oxígeno generadas y restantes.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/*Shared variables*/
int moleculas_H = 0; //number of hydrogen molecules
int moleculas_O = 0; //number of oxygen molecules
int moleculas_W = 0; //number of water molecules


pthread_t *worker_H; 
pthread_t *worker_O;
pthread_t worker_W;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


void *hidrogens(void * args) {
  printf("I'm an Hidrogen's thread.\n" );
  moleculas_H += 1;
  return (void *) 0;
}

void *oxygens(void * args) {
  printf("I'm an Oxygen's thread.\n");
  moleculas_O += 1;
  return (void *) 0;
}

void * water(void * args) {
  printf("I'm an Water's thread.\n");
  return (void *) 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    perror("Use: ./main numHidrog numOxig");
    return 0;
  }

  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  int M = atoi(argv[2]);

  worker_H = malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));
  worker_O = malloc(M * sizeof(pthread_t));
  
  for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
    pthread_create(&worker_H[i], NULL, hidrogens, &i); 
  }
  
  for (int i=0; i < M; i++){
    pthread_create(&worker_O[i], NULL, oxygens, &i);
  }
    pthread_create(&worker_W, NULL, water, NULL);

  int val;
  for (int i=0; i < N; i++) 
    pthread_join(worker_H[i],(void *) &val);
  for (int i=0; i < M; i++) 
    pthread_join(worker_O[i],(void *) &val);

  pthread_join(worker_W,(void *) &val);

  return 0;
}
```

ese es el codigo que me dan  debo completarlo , alguna idea